# Função dos arquivos .pyc em Python

Tags: python, bytecode

Se a linguagem Python é interpretada, por que motivo existem arquivos .pyc que são bytecodes compilados?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

O Python, assim como o Java, trabalha com uma máquina virtual. No caso do Java, é mandatório enviar à máquina virtual apenas o código compilado, portanto o código do `.class`. No Python, a própria máquina virtual trabalha com o compilador da linguagem, então ela aceita código Python puro `.py` como, também, sua versão em bytecode `.pyc`.

Sobre questão de uma linguagem ser chamada de interpretada e outra ser chamada de compilada: em ambos os casos, ocorre compilação e interpretação. No caso do Java, a compilação ocorre num momento anterior à execução, na chamada ao `javac` para fazer a transformação `.java -> .class`. Após ser gerado o `.class`, há a interpretação dos bytecodes gerados para executar o programa. Posso fazer uma analogia aqui com C e o processador da minha máquina x86; o `gcc` vai transformar o código C em linguagem de máquina x86, para que então o processador receba o binário e os execute.

Em Python, o processo de compilação não precisa ocorrer a priori, acontecendo em um momento posterior. Assim como em Java e em C, há sim uma leitura de código fazendo a validação de gramática (detecção de erros de sintaxe) e a transformação em algo mais fácil de operacionalizar. O resultado de uma compilação bem sucedida é um conjunto de bytecodes Python equivalentes ao código Python original. Após esse processo de compilação, passa-se para o interpretador de bytecodes fazer o tratamento deles, assim como a JVM (Java Virtual Machine) faz com o compilado do Java, análogo ao como o processador x86 faz com o binário gerado pela compilação do arquivo C.

Para evitar passar pelo processo inteiro de compilação novamente, que exige uma validação da gramática e procura por erros sintáticos, uma vez gerada a compilação do código Python, ela pode ser armazenada para uso futuro. Isso é feito por uma questão de otimização. Enquanto não houver mudanças em seu arquivo `.py` original, o `.pyc` gerado será fiel ao código desejado, comportando-se de maneira esperada. No momento que você altera o `.py`, há a detecção dessa mudança e o compilador Python entra em campo para gerar o novo `.pyc`.

Em casos em que não é possível gerar o arquivo `.pyc` (por exemplo, código Python rodando a partir de um sistema de arquivos somente leitura), essa otimização não ocorre, então sempre ocorrerá a compilação do código original para, então, ocorrer a interpretação e execução de seus bytecodes.

Comment: bem legal a resposta!

Comment: @jsbueno , tem alguma pergunta/resposta sobre arquivos `.pyo`? Eu havia pensado que havia coberto isto na minha resposta, mas lendo novamente percebi que não o fiz.

Comment: Arquivos `.pyo` são quase a mesma coisa que os `.pyc` - mas são gerados quando o Python é chamado com a opção `-O` de  "optimized" - na prática o compilador não gera o código de algumas instruções que deveriam ser usadas só pra depuração/testes como os comandos `assert`. A diferença dessa otimização costuma ser bem pequena, então não se encontram muitos arquivos `.pyo` por aí.

Comment: Nessa resposta talvez valesse a pena completar que a partir do Python 3.5 (ou será que foi do 3.4?), os arquivos`.pyc` passaram a ser colocados na pasta  `__pycache__` e com o nome e versão do compilador integrados ao nome do arquivo `.pyc` - isso permite que arquivos .py na mesma pasta possam ser executados por versões diferentes do Python sem conflito com o `pyc` gerado.

Comment: @jsbueno porei sim, obrigado pelas informações!