# Como funciona o __pycache__?

Tags: python, python-3.x, cache, bytecode

Pelo meu entendimento, o pycache como o nome diz, "cacheia" os dados do código, criando um arquivo **.pyc** escrito em bytecode.

Desse modo, o código é rodado um pouco mais rápido pela segunda vez. Mas como funciona de fato esse processo?

O interpretador cria esse arquivo .pyc em bytecode e quando roda pela segunda vez, ele (o interpretador) consegue ler mais rápido o bytecode do que o próprio código em python?

Comment: Relacionado: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/207379/112052

Comment: A questão é que ele não vai precisar de compilar novamente para bytecode, a menos que a fonte tenha sofrido alterações.

Answer (score -1):

`__pycache__` funciona da seguinte maneira, quando você executa um script em Python, o interpretador o compila para versão bytecode `pyc` e após isso guarda no diretório `__pycache__`.  Se você visualizar esse diretório, você encontrará vários arquivos com os nomes dos `.py`, porém com as extensões `.pyc` ou  `.pyo`. Se executar novamente o script .`py` e tiver uma versão .`pyc` ou `.pyo` no diretório `__pycache__`, vai ser inicializado mais rápido (processo semelhante ao `web cache`)

#### Boa prática

Quando você for compartilhar o seu código com outras pessoas, a prática comum é deletar esse diretório. Caso, você suba o seu código através de um controle de versão `git`, é necessário listar o `__pycache__` no arquivo .`gitignore`, para que a pasta não seja incluída no `git push`